# How can I put tags inside a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-development-server

I want to put my HTML and other tags like javascript in a PHP variable so I can use it multiple times.

I've tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
$alert = "<script>alert('alert in php')</script>"   
echo $alert;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it works! You just missed two semicolons in your code.

```
$alert = "<script>alert('alert in php');</script>"; /** Mind the semicolons! */
echo $alert;
```